# Hardware convertion : written data is different than my read data

Tags: data-conversion

I am testing a program executed partially on a MPC603 and partially on a MPC555.
I have to verify that some data is correctly "moved" from one processor to the other via a DPRAM.

I am guessing that at some point "someone" makes a conversion but I don't know how to find what kind of conversion is done.

Here are some examples:

```
Pt_Dpram->acq1 at 0x8D00008 = 0x3EB2
acq1 =  (0xA010538) = 1182451712 = 0x467AC800

Pt_Dpram->acq2 at 0x8D0000A = 0x5528
acq2 =  (0xA010540) = 1185566720 = 0x46AA5000

Pt_Dpram->acq3 at 0x8D0000C = 0x416E
acq3 =  (0xA010548) = 1107552036 = 0x4203E724

Pt_Dpram->acq4 at 0x8D0000E = 0x413C
acq4 =  (0xA010550) = 1107526232 = 0x42038258
```

Comment: The first two numbers are converted from integer to IEEE 754 floating point: `0x3EB2` is `16050` in decimal, `0x467AC800` is the hex representation of `16050.0`; it's the same for the second. Only half of an answer, as the 3rd and 4th do something else, but it might help.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) There was indeed another calculation on the others examples specific to the programm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answers from a collegue : the values in acqX are in Motorola binary format : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)

Here is a small software that does the conversion : http://www.hexworkshop.com/onlinehelp/500/html/idhelp_baseconv.htm